# Windowbuilder shortcut key

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, windowbuilder

How can I create a button with a shortcut key?

the result would display an underlined letter on the button label or the control.
The user can then press [Alt]+key to run the default `actionEvent` of the control.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you try? Did you google?

Comment: I've tried to look over all the control's properties without success.
On internet, I found something related to an actionMap. I looked complicated. This is why I'm wondering if there is a simpler option to do it. 

In other languages, you simlply prefix a '&' to the desired letter into the caption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> " I found something related to an actionMap. I looked complicated. "

It's *not* complicated at all. What you want to do is use an `Action` (which is *similar* to an `ActionListener` with a callback), which can be allocated to different components. You can use the same `Action` for a `JPanel` *and* the `JButton`.

Suppose you have this `Action`

```
Action printHelloAction = new AbstractAction("Print") {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
};
```

What you want to do is add that to the `ActionMap`, `InputMap` of the `JPanel`, *and* at the same time just add that `Action` to the `JButton`

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
InputMap im = panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_P, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK), "printAction");
ActionMap am = panel.getActionMap();
am.put("printAction", printHelloAction);    // add to JPanel ActionMap

JButton button = new JButton(printHelloAction); // add to JButton
button.setText("Print Hello");
```

You can see I used the same `Action` for the `JPanel` key bind and also the `JButton`.

See more [How to use Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)  and [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

---

Here's an example from the code above. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class KeyBindActionDemo {

    public KeyBindActionDemo() {
        Action printHelloAction = new AbstractAction("Print") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Hello");
            }
        };
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        InputMap im = panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_P, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK), "printAction");
        ActionMap am = panel.getActionMap();
        am.put("printAction", printHelloAction);

        JButton button = new JButton(printHelloAction);
        button.setText("Print Hello");

        panel.add(button);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new KeyBindActionDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Peeskillet for the explanation and the code sample. I really appreciate yout help!
regards